# Why is $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ called the groups of rationals modulo one?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, quotient-group

In the book of *Algebra* by Hungerford, at page 27, it is given that

The following relation on $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ 
$$aR b  \quad iff \quad a-b \in \mathbb{Z},$$
defined a congruence relation, and the set of equivalence classes $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is a group called **the groups of rationals modulo one.**

**Question:**

Why is $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ called the groups of rationals modulo one ?

---

Is it because we can identify all the equivalence classes with the rationals between $(0,1)$ plus the number $1$ ? (of course if this is true)

Comment: Do you rather mean $aRb$ if $a-b\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @edm Yep, thank for pointing out that typo.

Comment: I think it should be "modulo" instead of "module". Could you check the book again?

Comment: The generator of the group $\Bbb Z$ is $1$ ("one" in the English language).

Comment: what is the reason for the down vote ?

Comment: Are you familiar with quotient groups and congruences ("modulo" language)?

Comment: @BillDubuque yes

Comment: Is it correct, when I say that $\mathbb{Z}$ is also the identity of the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$? I stumbled across this interesting terminology question because I am dealing with $p$-Prüfer groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make an analogy between this and modulo in integers, recall that modulo $n$ means $\Bbb Z$ is taken quotient over the the (normal) subgroup generated by the element $n$.

So in this case of rational numbers, you take quotient of $\Bbb Q$ over the (normal) subgroup generated by the element $1$. This subgroup generated by $1$ is precisely $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: what about the other classes that do not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I don't understand your question. Are you asking what the equivalence classes look like?

Comment: Got it! Thanks. (I had the same question.) $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=(\mathbb{Q},+)/\langle 1\rangle$. $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow a-b\in \langle 1\rangle\Leftrightarrow a+\langle 1\rangle=b+\langle 1\rangle$. See p.37, Definition I.4.1.